Identity involving alternating multinomial terms
Take $x_{1},\ldots,x_{k + 1}$ to be distinct real numbers such that, with $k \geq 1$ some positive integer.
I want to show the following:
$$
0 = -\sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ \leq\ k + 1}x_{i}^{k} +
\sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ <\ j\ \leq\ k + 1}\left(x_{i} + x_{j}\right)^{k} - \cdots \left(-1\right)^{k}\left(x_{1} + \cdots + x_{k + 1}\right)^{k}
$$
This is from my Discrete Math Class, and what really tickles my brain is the thought of using the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion but I have no clue how to.
Any help would be great !.

We look at first at a small example $k=3$. We consider four pairwise different real numbers $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and want to show
\begin{align*}
0&=-\sum_{1\leq q_1\leq 4}x_{q_1}^3+\sum_{1\leq q_1<q_2\leq 4}\left(x_{q_1}+x_{q_2}\right)^3\\
&\qquad-\sum_{1\leq q_1<q_2<q_3\leq 4}\left(x_{q_1}+x_{q_2}+x_{q_3}\right)^3\\
&\qquad+\sum_{1\leq q_1<q_2<q_3<q_4\leq 4}\left(x_{q_1}+x_{q_2}+x_{q_3}+x_{q_4}\right)^3\tag{1}
\end{align*}
When we expand the cubic multinomials we get monomials which look like
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x_2^3,\qquad x_1^2x_4, \qquad x_1x_3x_4}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
that is, we have monomials consisting of one, two or three variables with sum of exponents equal to $k=3$. We show that each of these monomials is cancelled in (1). We start with
\begin{align*}
x_1^2x_4\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad\sum_{1\leq q_1<q_2<q_3\leq 4}\left(x_{q_1}+x_{q_2}+x_{q_3}\right)^3\tag{3}
\end{align*}

How many summands in (3) contain the monomial $x_1^2x_4$? We have three indices $q_1,q_2,q_3$, but since two of them are fix ($x_1$ and $x_4$ due to $x_1^2x_4$) we have to subtract two from $4$ and also to reduce the number of varying indices by two.
\begin{align*}
\binom{4-2}{3-2}=\binom{2}{1}
\end{align*}

How often does $x_1^{{\color{blue}{2}}}x_4^{{\color{blue}{1}}}$ occur in one cubed multinomial $\left(x_{1}+x_{4}+x_{q_j}\right)^{\color{blue}{3}}$? This number is
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\color{blue}{3}}!}{{\color{blue}{2}}!{\color{blue}{1}}!}
\end{align*}
and this number is the same for the number of occurrences of $x_1^2x_4$ in
\begin{align*}
\left(x_{1}+x_{2}\right)^3, (x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{q_j})^3\ \mathrm{and}\ 
(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{q_{j_1}}++x_{q_{j_2}})^3
\end{align*}
and zero for all multinomials with less than two summands. We conclude the monomial $x_1^2x^4$ occurs in (1):
\begin{align*}
&x_1^2x^4:\qquad\qquad\color{blue}{0-\binom{4-2}{2-2}\frac{3!}{2!1!}+\binom{4-2}{3-2}\frac{3!}{2!1!}-\binom{4-2}{4-2}\frac{3!}{2!1!}}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad=\frac{3!}{2!1!}\left(-\binom{2}{0}+\binom{2}{1}-\binom{2}{2}\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad=-\frac{3!}{2!1!}\left(1-1\right)^2\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
\end{align*}
Analogously we derive from (1) and (2):
\begin{align*}
&x_2^3:\qquad\qquad{\color{blue}{\frac{3!}{3!}\left(-\binom{3}{0}+\binom{3}{1}-\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{3}\right)}}
=-\frac{3!}{3!}(1-1)^3\color{blue}{=0}\\
&x_1x_3x_4:\qquad{\color{blue}{\frac{3!}{1!1!1!}\left(-\binom{1}{0}+\binom{1}{1}\right)}}=-\frac{3!}{1!1!1!}(1-1)^3\color{blue}{=0}\\
\end{align*}


General case: We derive the general case in a similar way as above, namely

\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\sum_{l=1}^{k+1}(-1)^l\sum_{1\leq q_1<q_2<\cdots <q_l\leq k+1}\left(x_{q_{1}}+x_{q_{2}}+\cdots+x_{q_{l}}\right)^k}\\
&\qquad=-\sum_{1\leq i \leq k+1} x_i^k + \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq k+1}(x_i+x_j)^k -...(-1)^k(x_1+...+x_{k+1})^k\\
&\qquad=\sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{
{{m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_n=k}\atop{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n\geq 1}}\atop{1\leq r_1<r_2<\cdots< r_n\leq k+1}}
\frac{k!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!}x_{r_1}^{m_1}x_{r_2}^{m_2}\cdots x_{r_n}^{m_n}\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot\underbrace{\sum_{l=n}^{k+1}(-1)^l\binom{k+1-n}{l-n}}_{=0}\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.

Here we use
\begin{align*}
\sum_{l=n}^{k+1}(-1)^l\binom{k+1-n}{l-n}&=(-1)^n\sum_{l=0}^{k+1-n}(-1)^l\binom{k+1-n}{l}\\
&=(-1)^n(1-1)^{k+1-n}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
